# How to assign same values if the values in two columns appear in reverse in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm new to python, and although it helped me a lot. In my data frame lot of duplicate values are there so I want to assign different values in the third column. Can you please help me with that

```
Column_a, Column_b, New

   6.       7.        1
   7.       6.        1
  11.       10.       2
  10.       11.       2
  12.       15.       3
  15.       12.       3
```

I want this type of output

Thanks and Regards

I have tried this

```
g['New']=pd.DataFrame(np.sort(g[['Column_a','Column_b']])).duplicated(keep=False).astype(int)



   6.       7.        1
   7.       6.        1
  11.       10.       1
  10.       11.       1
  12.       15.       1
  15.       12.       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your attempted code just marks every row that's duplicate of another (after the dataframe columns are sorted based on row values) as a duplicate (True) and converts it to 1's.

To assign a unique value to each group of duplicates, modify that code to increment a value for each group of duplicates:

```
df["New"] = 1
df['New'] = df.groupby(
    pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['Column_a','Column_b']])).duplicated(), sort=False
).New.cumsum()

print(df)
#   Column_a    Column_b    New
# 0        6           7      1
# 1        7           6      1
# 2       11          10      2
# 3       10          11      2
# 4       12          15      3
# 5       15          12      3
```

If your duplicates are not necessarily grouped in consecutive rows, you can also use this to assign unique values to each group:

```
df['New'] = pd.DataFrame(
    np.sort(df[['Column_a','Column_b']]), columns=['Column_a','Column_b']
).groupby(['Column_a','Column_b']).ngroup() + 1
```